# Pixel tearing on class change in CSS transition and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem of a little pixel tearing/sliding while executing a jQuery class switching and animating with a CSS Transition, using Bootstrap 3. It's like a single (or couple) pixel moves while doing the transition, but is something quite noticeable sometimes.

It happens in Firefox, Opera Legacy (below 15) and Webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Opera 15+). I don't know if this is a browser bug, a Bootstrap bug or something else.

Here's a fiddle of what I'm saying: http://www.bootply.com/84414

**Edit:** To make it more noticeable, change the transition time in the CSS. 3 seconds are more than enough to see it.

Comment: Curiously, when there's no scroll bar in the output panel, the images stay exactly where they are. Odd

Comment: @Bojangles Interesting, I didn't see that behavior in the site I'm building because it already has a scrollbar.

Does that mean it's a browser bug?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an old question but I stumbled across this when looking for a fix for a problem that I am experiencing.

Anyway it looks like your animation is tearing slightly. Try forcing it onto the hardware acceleration by applying this to the necessary elements.

```
*{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
```

I applied to all elements just as a test on your fiddle and it seemed to fix it